# Haskell monads and a fail that doesn't require a string

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have the following monad transformer for dealing with errors in Haskell.

```
instance (Monad m, Error e) => Monad (EitherT e m) where
    return = EitherT . return . return
    m >>= k  = EitherT $ do
            a <- runEitherT m
            case a of
                Left  l -> return (Left l)
                Right r -> runEitherT (k r)
    fail = EitherT . return . Left . strMsg
```

It works fairly well, as I can instantiate `Error` with a custom class and have a pretty flexible means by which to handle errors.

`fail` is a bit silly, though, because it is type `String -> EitherT e m`, and the `String` restriction can be an annoying way to create errors. I end up with a whole lot of:

```
instance Error BazError where
    strMsg "foo" = FooError -- oh look we have no error context
    strMsg "bar" = BarError -- isn't that nice
```

What I'd like to do is create a new function, like `fail`, that is of type `a -> e` so that I can remove the `(Error e)` restriction. `fail` is especially convenient when the monad stack gets large, like when I end up with

```
EitherT BazError (StateT [BazWarning] IO) Foo
```

Is there a way to create a function that has the same behavior as `fail` with a less restrictive type? Or is `fail` implemented using deep haskell dark magic?

Comment: You should probably simply avoid `fail` entirely, unless you want to customise the behaviour on failed `do`-block pattern matches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `fail` is called if you have a pattern-match failure in a do block, like if you have `Just x <- something` and `something`'s result is `Nothing`. Apart from that, `fail` is an ordinary function.

For the problem with `strMsg "foo" = FooError` etc, does `throwError` offer a nicer interface for your use case?

Answer (score 4):

This article may be useful: http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/08/8-ways-to-report-errors-in-haskell-revisited/

Your EitherT is already in the standard library and called `ErrorT`. See the documentation: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Error.html#t:ErrorT

`fail` is a historical curiosity now, and may considered a design flaw, along with lack of `Functor a => Monad a` constraint. It is only a controversial feature to handle failed pattern matches in `do` notation.

```
throwError :: MonadError e m => e -> m a
```

is the most common replacement for `fail`, but more are available (see the article).